# Why can't I override the method definition in the class(function) description?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, overriding, prototype

I don't really understand,  why do I get in the first log message `Prototype: [object Object]`, and in the second it's `Prototype: New Plant`?

```
function Plant() {
this.toString = function() {
        return "Plant";
    }
}

function Fruit(name) {
    Plant.call(this);
    this.name = name;
    this.toString = function() {
        return "Fruit";
    }
}
Fruit.prototype = Object.create(Plant.prototype);     
var apple = new Fruit("apple");

console.log("Prototype: " + Object.getPrototypeOf(apple));
Plant.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "New Plant";
}
console.log("Prototype: " + Object.getPrototypeOf(apple));
```

I thought since I defined toString() method in the Plant class, all Fruit instances would have this method too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your Fruit instances *do* have access to the `.toString()` method on the Plant prototype. However, that method is *overridden* by a direct assignment in the Fruit constructor. Once the Fruit constructor assigns something to `this.toString`, that will always hide the `.toString()` in the prototype chain.

Remember in that in the code for the Fruit constructor, `this` refers to the newly-created instance. Assignments to properties of `this` are therefore properties that will exist directly on every instance.

In any expression like `x.toString()`, the search for a property whose name is "toString" starts at the object itself. If it's found there, then the prototype chain is not consulted at all.

Now, as to the other question of why your `console.log()` statements print what they do, note that the *first* call happens *before* you put a `.toString()` method on the Plant prototype. Once you've done that, the conversion from object to string that happens in the `+` expression in the call to `console.log()` will implicitly call that function to convert the prototype object to a string.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! However, if I remove toString() description from the Fruit function, I still have the same response on the first invocation of Object.getPrototypeOf(apple)  - it's Prototype: [object Object].
Shouldn't it be "Plant" since the search will follow the prototype chain from Fruit to Plant and I have toString() in the Plant function?

Comment: @AntonPoliakov yes - because you're using `Object.getPrototypeOf(apple)` with the `+` operator, and the default `.toString()` from the Object prototype function will be called, and it returns `[object Object]`.  Remember, the prototype object is *itself* an object, and the only `.toString()` available from the *prototype* object is the one on `Object.prototype`. The fact that Fruit *instances* get a `.toString()` function doesn't matter.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!